# Create more than one users via shared preference

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, sharedpreferences

Hello everyone i trying a create small login & register application. This application will keep more than one users and their passwords on it. I'm using a Shared preferences for saving the data. But I don't know how to save multiple users & passwords. so i can login in app via different usernames & passwords.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be unwise, I recommend using a DB.

Comment: I agree with @Eyosiyas but if you still want to use shared preferences you can store your users as a HashSet<String>.  
More info about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057858/8208808